# SQL Multiple "LEFT JOIN" and "GROUP BY" with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a `report` **per customer** (`Cliente` column), which sum some values, I reached that but couldn't group them by `Cliente` (*customer*)

---

I parcially reached my goal with this SQL command below, but I still got a problem, I need to group all results by `Cliente`

```
SELECT  
 TAB_Aditivos.Cliente As Col1,
 FORMAT(TAB_Aditivos.Diferencial + TAB_Aditivos.[Ad Valorem] + IIF(ConsiderarJ = 0, TAB_Aditivos.[IOF Adicional], 0) + IIF(ConsiderarJ = 0, TAB_Aditivos.IOF, 0) + TAB_Aditivos.[Outros Créditos] - TAB_Aditivos.[Outros Débitos] + ISNULL(Juros,0),'C') As Col2
FROM TAB_Aditivos 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_Aditivo, SUM(Juros) AS Juros FROM TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos GROUP BY ID_Aditivo) TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos ON TAB_Aditivos.ID_Aditivo = TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos.ID_Aditivo 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Considerar AS ConsiderarJ FROM TAB_Lojas) TAB_Lojas ON TAB_Aditivos.Loja = TAB_Lojas.ID
WHERE 
 TAB_Aditivos.[Data Aditivo] >= @DataInicial
ORDER BY 
 Cliente ASC
```

I'm getting these results, they're correct, but I need to group them by `Cliente`.

| Cliente | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 606 | R$ 170,99 |
| 606 | R$ 337,06 |
| 606 | R$ 1.905,22 |
| 607 | R$ 411,40 |
| 607 | R$ 76,26 |
| 607 | R$ 482,02 |
| 607 | R$ 67,64 |
| 608 | R$ 156,25 |
| 608 | R$ 682,41 |
| 608 | R$ 147,79 |
| 608 | R$ 344,16 |
| 609 | R$ 355,82 |
| 609 | R$ 890,40 |
| 609 | R$ 220,78 |

That's the results what I need:

| Cliente | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 606 | R$ 2.413,27 |
| 607 | R$ 1.037,32 |
| 608 | ... |
| 609 | ... |

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: That's right... I removed image from the tables...

Comment: It doesn't mean we don't want the data (and it applies to your results as well), it just means we want it as formatted text instead of an image.

Comment: Please add the sample data that should lead to your expected result, and also provide us whit the expected result. And, like asked before, provide it as text not as an image

Comment: The sample data is like "Result" imagem, the only difference will be that this value will be bigger because sum of `Juros` when `Cliente` matches @GuidoG

Comment: Well it's up to you, but if you want help then please do not add sample data as image, but as text. Do you really expect us to type over your sample data from an image so we can do some tests ? Add clear sample data as text, and add very clear what you expect as result from that sample data.

Comment: I made some Edits in topic, please take a look, thanks for the tips @GuidoG

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not see any sample data and clear expected outcome

Comment: Oh, I though I should remove images... I added a image with sample data, I think it'll be clear now, take a look... @GuidoG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so all you need is a group by ?

```
select t.Col1,
       sum(t.Col2)
from   ( SELECT TAB_Aditivos.Cliente As Col1,
                FORMAT(TAB_Aditivos.Diferencial + TAB_Aditivos.[Ad Valorem] + IIF(ConsiderarJ = 0, TAB_Aditivos.[IOF Adicional], 0) + IIF(ConsiderarJ = 0, TAB_Aditivos.IOF, 0) + TAB_Aditivos.[Outros Créditos] - TAB_Aditivos.[Outros Débitos] + ISNULL(Juros,0),'C') As Col2
         FROM   TAB_Aditivos 
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_Aditivo, SUM(Juros) AS Juros FROM TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos GROUP BY ID_Aditivo) TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos ON TAB_Aditivos.ID_Aditivo = TAB_Aditivos_Devolvidos.ID_Aditivo 
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Considerar AS ConsiderarJ FROM TAB_Lojas) TAB_Lojas ON TAB_Aditivos.Loja = TAB_Lojas.ID
         WHERE  TAB_Aditivos.[Data Aditivo] >= @DataInicial
       ) t
group by t.Col1
order by t.Col1
```